# InsertStyleSeparator() add white space with text in start of section [Aspose Word]

Tags: .net, aspose, aspose.words

I am using .net aspose word api to generate word document but after page break when i use insertStyleSeparator() it add white space with first and second line text. Anyone have any work around for that?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds that you are using Style Separator improperly. Style Separator is used when you need to format parts for a single paragraph with different styles. But from your description you can achieve what you need with normal paragraphs and [ParagraphFormat.PageBreakBefore](https://reference.aspose.com/words/net/aspose.words/paragraphformat/pagebreakbefore/) property to init page break instead of explicit page break. For example see the following code:

```cs
Document doc = new Document();
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    // to make a title to move to new page set ParagraphFormat.PageBreakBefore property.
    builder.ParagraphFormat.PageBreakBefore = true;
    builder.ParagraphFormat.StyleIdentifier = StyleIdentifier.Title;
    builder.Writeln("Section title:");

    // Clear paragraph format to reset ParagraphFormat.PageBreakBefore property.
    builder.ParagraphFormat.ClearFormatting();
    // Now DocumentBuilder cursor is in a new paragraph, so we can reset the style
    builder.ParagraphFormat.StyleIdentifier = StyleIdentifier.Normal;

    // Insert an empty paragraph
    builder.Writeln();

    // Insert content
    builder.Writeln("This is a section content.");
}

doc.Save(@"C:\Temp\out.docx");
```